# SendKeys circumflex results in ampersand

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys

C#'s `SendKeys.SendWait` behaves "interesting":

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{^}");
```

puts an ampersand `&` into the text box. Why's that? How to fix that?

(Note: this happens in de_AT culture only)

(The target application is not the issue, I've already tried it with a sample WinForms application as well)

Comment: The culture is not the issue (changing the culture does nothing); to reproduce this problem, set your keyboard layout to German (Austria); no further culture settings are necessary.

Comment: (Shift-6): US keyboard: `^` ... German keyboard: `&` ... So `{^}` is interpreted as Shift-6 and 'translated' to German (or should I say Austrian)

Comment: Thought so too, however, this "translation" does not happen for other keys. E.g. `&` works like a charm - although it can certainly not be on the same key ;-)

Comment: Does it? Because if I switch to Austrian layout and use `SendKeys.SendWait("&")`, sure enough, I get "/" (shift-7).

Comment: Yes, it works. I've entered: `! " § $ {%} & / {(} {)} =  ? ° ² ³ {{} {[} {]} {}} \ {+} * {~} {'} # @ A Z a z 0 1 8 9` which works like a charm. Only the `^` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `SendKeys` uses the Win32 function `SendInput` under the covers, and this function operates through virtual key codes, not actual strings. To send "^", it effectively produces shift-6, which in the Austrian keyboard layout produces "&". As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys) on `SendKeys` obliquely warns: "If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided."